# Retrieve auto increment

Tags: php, mysql, database

last entered auto increments data. In my case the owner_ID of the previously entered record into the mySQL database.

```
<?php
require "formfunctions.inc.php";
require "connect.inc.php";

startPage("Add details");

connectAndSelect(); //Uses my include php script functions to logon to mySQL using my credentials or die

if(isset($_POST['addDetails']))            //isset means Is Set, so this makes clicking the submit button true
{
  errorCheckDetails();
}
else
{
  showAddFormDetails();
}

endPage();
?>
```

Here is the functions include file:

```
<?php

/*This is a PHP script containing the majority of my forms, which I have made into functions. It keeps all the back-end data together, meaning the other PHP
files are a lot simpler, as I only need to call the functions if I need to use any of them, less code repitition meaning maximum efficency.

Again it is a required script so files relying on this will have it being required and will not parse if this file cannot be parsed by the server.*/

//******************************THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED AT THE BEGINNING OF EVERY PAGE, IT SETS UP THE DOCTYPE, DEFAULT COMMENT, NAVBAR, AND DIV TAGS TO BE DISPLAYED***************

function startPage($title = '')
{
  echo "<!doctype html>
<!--NICK LITTLE
  WEB 2 ASSIGNMENT 2- THE MOTOR VEHICLE REGISTER DATABASE-->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>$title</title>
    <link href='css.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='header'>
      <img src='header.jpg'/>
      <ul id='list-nav'>
        <li><a href='frontend.php'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='search.php'>Search/Delete</a></li>
        <li><a href='addowner.php'>Add New Owner & Vehicle</a></li>
        <li><a href='addvehicle.php'>Add Vehicle</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='content'>";
}

//**********SIMILAR TO THE START PAGE, CLOSES OFF DIV DAGS AND HTML BODY AND ENDING**********************************************************************************

function endPage()
{
  echo "
      </div>   
        </div>
  </body>
</html>";
}


//****************THIS FORM IS DISPLAYED ON THE ADD OWNER/VEHICLE PAGE. IT JUST DISPLAYS THE FORM FOR USER INPUT**************************************************************************  
function showAddFormDetails()
{
  $self=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];        //making the form self referring

  //start form display - EVERYTHING IS DISPLAYED IN A NICE LOOKING FORM

  echo "<form action='$self' method='POST'>  
    <center>
      <table id='searchForm'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan ='2'>Owner</th>
          <th colspan ='2'> Vehicle</th>             
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type='submit' name='addDetails' value='Add Details'/></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Title:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='title' size='5px'/></td>
          <td>Make:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='make' size='20px'/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='name' size='25px'/></td>
          <td>Model</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='model' size='20px'/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Address:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='address' size='48px'/></td>
          <td>Year:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='year' size='10px'/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Phone:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='phonenumber' size='10px'/></td>
          <td>Registration:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='rego' size='10px'/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>Kilometres:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='kms' size='10px'/></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>";
}

//**********FUNCTION TO DISPLAY FORM TO ADD A VEHICLE TO AN EXISTING OWNER*******************************************************************************************************

function showAddFormVehicle()   //SELECT NAME FROM THE OWNER ID TO PERFORM AN SQL QUERY ON
{
  $self=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];        //making the form self referring

  //start form display - EVERYTHING IS DISPLAYED IN A NICE LOOKING FORM
  echo"Please fill out the required fields to add a vehicle to the system<br /><br />
    Please note: A vehicle must be added to an <strong>existing owner</strong><br /><br />
    Click here to <a href='addowner.php'> add a new owner and vehicle</a>

  <form action='$self' method='POST'>  
    <center>
      <table id='searchForm'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan ='2'> Vehicle</th>             
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type='submit' name='addVehicle' align='right' value='Add Vehicle'/></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Owner:</td>
          <td><select name='owner_ID'><option value='-1' selected='selected'>Please select an owner...</option>";

  $selectString ="SELECT DISTINCT owner_ID, name FROM tblOwner";

  $result=mysql_query($selectString);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      $owner_ID = $row['owner_ID'];
      $owner_name = $row['name'];
      echo "<option value='$owner_ID'>$owner_name</option>";
    }    
        echo"</select>

          <tr>
            <td>Make:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='make' size='20px'/></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Model:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='model' size='20px'/></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            `<td>Year:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='year' size='10px'/></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Registration:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='rego' size='10px'/></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Kilometres:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='kms' size='10px'/></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>";
  }

//************FUNCTION TO ERROR CHECK THE INPUT ON THE ADDING A VEHICLE PAGE - SLIGHT VARIATION ON ADDING NEW VEHICLE AND OWNER SIMULTANEOUSLY**************************************************
function delete()
{
    /*foreach($_POST as $field => $value)
  {
    /*echo "$value<br>
        $field<br>";
  }*/

    $vehicleArray = $_POST['deleteButton'];
    $size = sizeOf( $vehicleArray);




    /*echo "SIZE is: $size<br>";            //SIZE returns a '1'
    echo "ARRAY is: $vehicleArray";
    echo" $vehicleArray[0]";
    //First index of array is a 'D'*/

    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)           //LOOP THROUGH THE SIZE AND ARRAY
    {
      $num = $vehicleArray[$i];
      $query = "DELETE FROM tblVehicle WHERE vehicle_ID='$num'";
      //echo"$query";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      echo "Thank you, the selected vehicle(s) were removed from the system <br />
        <i> Please note the OWNER of the vehicle will remain in the system </i>";
    }  
}

//*****************************THIS FUNCTION ERROR CHECKS USER INPUT WHEN ATTEMPTING TO INSERT AN OWNER**************************************************************************

function errorCheckDetails()
{
  //assigning variables to the fields filled in, creates variables and assigns to 'NAME' form input value------


  //----------owner variables----------------//
  $ownerTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
  $ownerName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
  $ownerAddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
  $ownerPhone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phonenumber']);

  //--------vehicle variables------------//
  $vehicleMake = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['make']);
  $vehicleModel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['model']);
  $vehicleYear = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
  $vehicleRego = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rego']);
  $vehicleKms = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kms']);

  $allFilled = true;

  //checking to see that all individual fields are filled in:
  if (empty($_POST['title'])==0)
    $allFilled = false;           //If a specefic form field is empty, it is set to true, or else it is false

  if (empty($_POST['name'])==0)
    $allFilled = false;

  if (empty($_POST['address'])==0)
    $allFilled = false;

  if (empty($_POST['phonenumber'])==0)
    $allFilled = false;

  if (empty($_POST['make'])==0)
    $allFilled = false;

  if (empty($_POST['model'])==0)
    $allFilled = false;

  if (empty($_POST['year'])==0)
    $allFilled = false;

  if (empty($_POST['rego'])==0)
    $allFilled = false;

  if (empty($_POST['kms'])==0)
    $allFilled = false;


  //providing if all of the fields are filled in, insert user's data into owner table, all required fields

if ($allFilled)
{
//*********************************************mySQL queries**********************************************************

  $insertOwnerQuery="INSERT INTO tblOwner(title,name,address,phone)
            VALUES ('$ownerTitle','$ownerName','$ownerAddress','$ownerPhone')";

  $result=mysql_query($insertOwnerQuery);

  $aOwner = mysql_insert_id();           //Assign variable to mySQL function, returns last known user id input, so as to determine auto_inc for owner_ID

  $insertVehicleQuery="INSERT INTO tblVehicle(owner_ID,make,model,year,rego,kms)
            VALUES ('$aOwner','$vehicleMake','$vehicleModel','$vehicleYear','$vehicleRego','$vehicleKms')";

  $result=mysql_query($insertVehicleQuery); 



echo "Thank you, your entry has been added to the system";  //Echo to screen to inform user owner has been added successfully.
}
else
  {
    //error messages that appear for each individual field that is not filled in:
    if (empty($_POST["title"]))
      echo"<p>The 'Owner Title' field must be filled in.</p>";

    if (empty($_POST["name"]))
      echo "<p>The 'Name' field must be filled in.</p>";

    if (empty($_POST["address"]))
      echo "<p>The 'Address' field must be filled in.</p>";

    if (empty($_POST["phonenumber"]))
      echo "<p>The 'Phone Number' field must be filled in.</p>";

    if (empty($_POST["make"]))
      echo "<p>The 'Vehicle Make' field must be filled in.</p>";

    if (empty($_POST["model"]))
      echo "<p>The 'Vehicle Model' field must be filled in.</p>";

    if (empty($_POST["year"]))
      echo "<p>The 'Vehicle Year' field must be filled in.</p>";

    if (empty($_POST["rego"]))
      echo "<p>The 'Vehicle Registration' field must be filled in.</p>";

    if (empty($_POST["kms"]))
      echo "<p>The 'Vehicle Kilometers' field must be filled in.</p>";
  }

/*echo '<form action = '$self' method='POST'>
      <input type='submit' name='returnAddOwner' value='Return to Adding an Owner'>    
    </form>';*/
}

//************FUNCTION TO ERROR CHECK THE INPUT ON THE ADDING A VEHICLE PAGE - SLIGHT VARIATION ON ADDING NEW VEHICLE AND OWNER SIMULTANEOUSLY**************************************************

function errorCheckVehicle()
{
  //assigning variables to the fields filled in, creates variables and assigns to 'NAME' form input value------

  //----------owner variables----------------//

  $owner_ID = $_POST['owner_ID'];   //NEED 2 FIGURE OUT HOW TO DETECT OPTION VALUE FOR OWNER NAME

  //--------vehicle variables------------//
  $vehicleMake = $_POST['make'];
  $vehicleModel = $_POST['model'];
  $vehicleYear = $_POST['year'];
  $vehicleRego = $_POST['rego'];
  $vehicleKms = $_POST['kms'];

  $allFilled = true;

  //checking to see that all individual fields are filled in:

  if ($vehicleMake == "") $allFilled = false;
  if ($vehicleModel == "") $allFilled = false;
  if ($vehicleYear == "") $allFilled = false;
  if ($vehicleRego == "") $allFilled = false;
  if ($vehicleKms == "") $allFilled = false;

  //providing if all of the fields are filled in, insert user's data into owner table, all required fields
  if ($allFilled)
  {    
    $insertVehicleQuery="INSERT INTO tblVehicle(owner_ID,make,model,year,rego,kms)
      VALUES ('$owner_ID','$vehicleMake','$vehicleModel','$vehicleYear','$vehicleRego','$vehicleKms')";

    $result=mysql_query($insertVehicleQuery); 

    echo "Thank you, the vehicle has been added to the system";  //Echo to screen to inform user owner has been added successfully.
  }

//error messages that appear for each individual field that is not filled in:
  else
  {

    if (empty($_POST["make"]))
      echo "<p>The 'Vehicle Make' field must be filled in.</p>";

    if (empty($_POST["model"]))
      echo "<p>The 'Vehicle Model' field must be filled in.</p>";

    if (empty($_POST["year"]))
      echo "<p>The 'Vehicle Year' field must be filled in.</p>";

    if (empty($_POST["rego"]))
      echo "<p>The 'Vehicle Registration' field must be filled in.</p>";

    if (empty($_POST["kms"]))
      echo "<p>The 'Vehicle Kilometers' field must be filled in.</p>";
  }
}

//*********************************************************DISPLAY SEARCH FORM ON PAGE************************************************************************

  function showSearchForm()
  {
    $self=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];        //making the form self referring

    echo "
      <form action='$self' method='POST'>
        <center>
          <table id='searchForm'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colspan='2'>Vehicle</th>
                <th colspan='2'>Owner</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class='searchSubmitButtons'><input type='submit' name='search' value='Search Records' /></td>
                <td class='searchSubmitButtons'><input type='submit' name='search' value='List all database entries' /></td>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Make:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='vehiclemake' size='20' /></td>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='ownername' size='25' /></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>Model:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='vehiclemodel' size='20' /></td>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='owneraddress' size='48' /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><label for='vehicleyear'>Year:</label></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='vehicleyear' id='vehicleyear' size='10' /></td>
                <td>Phone:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='ownerphone'/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Registration:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='vehiclerego' size='10' /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Km's:</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' name='vehiclekms' size='10'/></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
      </form>";
  }




  function showRecords()
  {
    $self=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];        //making the form self referring

    //assigning variables to the fields filled in:
    //$owner_ID = $_POST['ownerID'];
    //$title = $_POST['ownertitle'];
    $name = $_POST['ownername'];
    $address = $_POST['owneraddress'];
    $phone = $_POST['ownerphone'];

    $make = $_POST['vehiclemake'];
    $model = $_POST['vehiclemodel'];
    $year = $_POST['vehicleyear'];
    $rego = $_POST['vehiclerego'];
    $kms = $_POST['vehiclekms'];

//print search results from both tables - patients and owners (unnecessary fields or duplicates excluded) % is the like function, so could put 'at' to get cat:
    $selectString = "SELECT vehicle_ID,make,model,year,rego,kms,name,phone 
                FROM tblVehicle,tblOwner 
                  WHERE (tblVehicle.owner_ID = tblOwner.owner_ID

                  AND make LIKE '%$make%' 
                  AND model LIKE '%$model%' 
                  AND rego LIKE '%$rego%' 
                  AND kms LIKE '%$kms%'  


                  AND name LIKE '%$name%'
                  AND address LIKE '%$address%' 
                  AND phone LIKE '%$phone%')";
    $result = mysql_query($selectString);

    //vehicle_ID, tblOwner.owner_ID,


    echo"<form action = '$self' method='POST'>
    <table border='1' cellpadding='8'>
          <tr>
            <th>Vehicle ID</th>
            <th>Vehicle Make</th>
            <th>Vehicle Model</th>
            <th>Vehicle Year</th>
            <th>Vehicle Registration</th>
            <th>Vehicle KM</th>
            <th>Owner Name</th>
            <th>Owner Phone</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>";



    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
      echo '<tr>';

      foreach($row as $field => $value)
      {    
        if( $field == 0)
          $vehicle_ID=$value;
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
      }

      echo"<td><input type ='checkbox' name = deleteButton[] value='$vehicle_ID'></td>";    
      echo '</tr>';
    }

  echo "</table>
    <br><br>

          <input type='submit' name='returnSearch' value='Return to Searching Records'>    



        <input type='submit' name='del' align='right' value='Delete Selected Records'>

      </form>";

  }
































?>
```

Sorry they are big files. Im new here :( Don't know how to post big amounts of code.

Cheers

Comment: You already have `$aOwner = mysql_insert_id();` in the functions' file, what else do you want?

Comment: I dont really get the question, but if you want to get the last ID entered to the DB (it doesnt matter if its auto increments or not) use a sql query to get data in a desc order and limit it to one

Comment: or if the query is on the same page, use this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 2):

you are answering your own question

in your code

```
  $aOwner = mysql_insert_id(); //Assign variable to mySQL function, returns last known user id input, so as to determine auto_inc for owner_ID
```

so just print the $aOwner

Comment: Correct! But this code is not putting the record in the database

Comment: can your print out the $aOwner and see if it show you the latest id of the table tblOwner or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

or in php

```
mysql_query("INSERT ... ");
$increment = mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

@genesis I believe you want to display the next incremement 
    owner_ID
where a user know, what will be his/her owner_ID.

If i am right read below information

1] retrive the owner_ID from tblVehicle table,
2] take the highest number,
3] increment the highest number with 1,
4] then go with the insertion code,

And i tested with queries listed above

> SELECT from table_name LAST_INSERT_ID()

or

> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

these two queries didnt work out, i provides only '0' values.

better try up with code insertion

```
$insertVehicleQuery="INSERT INTO tblVehicle(make,model,year,rego,kms) VALUES ('$vehicleMake','$vehicleModel','$vehicleYear','$vehicleRego','$vehicleKms')";
```

just remove the *owner_ID* from the above query

Answer (score -1):

[mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

```
$result = mysql_query(SELECT from table_name LAST_INSERT_ID())";
echo $result;
```

[php reference](https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id)

```
mysql_query("watever query");
echo  mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get this by

```
$r = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table_name' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($r);
$Auto_increment = $row['Auto_increment'];
mysql_free_result($r);
```